# Coolers noise at Dell XPS 15 9550 without heavy loading

Tags: dual-boot, dell, xps, sensors

I have a Dell XPS 15 9550. Succesfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows. All is fine, but coolers works on max without using something heavy. At Windows all is ok. I read that this is known problem at laptops with Linux, but no one tutorial doesnt helps me. May be here someone know how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

This should solve it, did it for me. The culprit is gvfsd-smb-browse process.

Add the statement below to [global] section of your /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
name resolve order = wins lmhosts bcast
```

https://itsfoss.com/fix-gvfsd-smb-high-cpu-ubuntu/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.